# Java Socket Client Returns Bad Characters as response for AT commands sent to the connected Modem

Tags: java, sockets, at-command

I am testing a java code to issue AT Commands to the Modem at the designated port. I was able to successfully make Socket connection to the Modem's default gateway IP and AT Command port and write AT commands to that socket. (something like below)

```
Socket socket = new Socket(address, port);
socket.setKeepAlive(true);
...
String command = "AT\r\n";
...
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
byte[] commandBytes = command.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
out.write(commandBytes, 0, commandBytes.length);
out.flush();
```

And try to read the response from the socket as below

```
BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
byte[] byteArray = new byte[1024];
int count = in.read(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
System.out.println("Response Received: " + new String(byteArray, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII));
```

The problem is, I am getting bad characters (like `??`) as the response. I am expecting the output as "OK". When I issue the same command from the command prompt of the same PC where I am running this code, I am getting the response in proper English. I am assuming (mostly true) that the modem might be using a different language like C, C++ and their byte rage is different from the byte range of Java. But if this is the case, I am not sure how to fix it. Need help.

Things that I have already tried:

- Printed the bytes as retrieved and found that these are of negative byte values (like -1, -3, -5 etc)
- Verified the default of charset of the modem and if found to be ISO-8859-1 and tried using the same in my code (both write and read) still getting similar bad characters only
- Tried reading as characters using BufferredReader* classed, but nothing is getting received at the response

My question in short, how to read the binary(byte array) data received as response from Modem for the given AT commands issued from Java Socket Connection?

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Comment: You have to find out the details of the protocol for communicating with the modem.

Comment: Yes, protocol is TCP using Socket programming

Comment: I'm a bit confused: are you communicating through sockets or through AT commands? The latter is a serial communication protocol (through rs332, usb... a serial device in general). Then, through AT commands you can configurate the modem so that it sets up TCP connections, but that's another sport. If, instead, you have some special system with a (external) server forwarding AT commands to a remote modem, you should describe better tgat system. Please, clarify also the modem model and link its documentation: any special feature could be described there.

Comment: Yes, AT commands are basically serial communication protocol. But there is a provision to communicate to the modem using AT commands over LAN interface. For that I was trying to use TCP protocol but couldn't decode the response properly. Later I modified the code to use Telnet to connect and communicate with Modem using AT commands, this response (received from telnet) is now decode-able in Java